# PHP SoapClient: mostrar resultado en tabla HTML

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Tengo este código para consumir un `web service`:

```
<?php

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 900);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);

$wsdl = 'http://servidor/servicio.svc?WSDL';
$options = array(
        'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
        'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout'=>15,
        'trace'=>true,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'exceptions'=>true,
    );

try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = $soap->__soapCall('ObtenerPaises', []);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

var_dump($data);
die;

?>
```

El resultado que arroja este `web service` es este:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["ObtenerDelegacionResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["Delegaciones"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["Delegacion"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["Codigo"]=> string(8) "1-MADRID" ["Nombre"]=> string(6) "Madrid" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["Codigo"]=> string(10) "2-TENERIFE" ["Nombre"]=> string(8) "Tenerife" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["Codigo"]=> string(13) "3- LAS PALMAS" ["Nombre"]=> string(10) "Las Palmas" } } } ["Mensaje"]=> string(0) "" ["Result"]=> string(2) "OK" } }
```

**¿Qué tengo que hacer para que el resultado se mostrado en una tabla similar a esta?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta con esto

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Codigo</th> <th>Nombre</th> </tr>";
foreach($data->ObtenerDelegacionResult->Delegaciones->Delegacion as $row){
  echo "<tr> <td>{$row->Codigo}</td> <td>{$row->Nombre}</td> </tr>"
}
echo "</table>";
```